# Unity3D ScrollView scroll range

Tags: layout, position, scrollview, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a scrollView, but I don't know how to determine the maximum range of the scroll (or even better, the maximum scroll position).

This is what I have tried to do without any positive results:

```
void Update()
{
  //get the amount of space that my text is taking
  textSize = gs.CalcHeight(new GUIContent(text), (screenWidth/2));

  if(Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved && Input.GetTouch(0).tapCount==1) 
  {
    var touch = Input.touches[0];

   //check if touch is within the scrollView area
   if(touch.position.x >= (screenWidth/2) && touch.position.x <= (screenWidth) && touch.position.y >= 0 && touch.position.y <= (screenHeight))
   {
     if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
     {
       scrollPosition[1] += touch.deltaPosition.y;
       if(scrollPosition[1] < 0)
       {
           scrollPosition[1] = 0;
       }

       //I subtracted this cause i read that the scrollbars take 16px
       if(scrollPosition[1] > (textSize-scrollViewRect.yMax-16)) //scrollViewRect is a Rect with the size of my scrollView
       {
          scrollPosition[1] = textSize-scrollViewRect.yMax-16;
       }
     }
   }
  }
}

void OnGUI()
{
 screenWidth = camera.pixelWidth;
 screenHeight = camera.pixelHeight;
 GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(screenWidth/2, 0, screenWidth/2, screenHeight));

 GUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPosition/*, GUILayout.Width (screenWidth/2), GUILayout.Height (screenHeight/2)*/, "box");

 GUILayout.Label (new GUIContent(text), gs);

 // End the scrollview
 GUILayout.EndScrollView ();
 scrollViewRect = GUILayoutUtility.GetLastRect();
 GUILayout.EndArea();
}
```

This was done assuming that the scrollView is on the right half of the screen.

Can you guys help me out on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have have fixed items it can be calculated, for example draw a list of labels bounded within a box and then calc the amount of items * the box height. I used that trick before.

Answer (score 3):

As shown in the API documentation for [GUI.BeginScrollView](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUI.BeginScrollView.html), you can assign a Vector2 to the declaration of BeginScrollView to track and update where the box has been scrolled to.

I'll give an example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ScrollSize : MonoBehaviour {

private int screenBoxX  = Screen.width;
private int screenBoxY  = Screen.height;

private int scrollBoxX  = Screen.width  * 2;
private int scrollBoxY  = Screen.height * 3;

public Vector2 scrollPosition = Vector2.zero;

void Awake()
{
    Debug.Log ("box size is " + scrollBoxX + " " + scrollBoxY); 
}

void OnGUI()     
{
    scrollPosition = GUI.BeginScrollView(new Rect(0, 0, screenBoxX, screenBoxY),
                         scrollPosition, new Rect(0, 0, scrollBoxX, scrollBoxY));

    GUI.EndScrollView();

    // showing 4 decimal places
    Debug.Log ("Box scrolled @ " + scrollPosition.ToString("F4"));
}
}
```

For the explanation of this example, let's assume that the screen resolution is 800 by 600.
Therefore the viewable scrollbox on the screen will be 800 wide and 600 high, with the internal area of the scrollbox being 1600 by 1800.

We create the scrollbox by assigning Gui.BeginScrollView() as the value of Vector2, scrollPosition. As the scrollbox is scrolled horizontally and vertically, the Vector2 will update with the scrolled value.

If the scrollbox is scrolled to the top-leftmost position, the value of scrollPosition will be 0,0.

If the scrollbox is scrolled to the bottom-rightmost position, the value of scrollPosition will be 816, 616, the size of the box on screen plus the thickness of the scroll bars.

Comment: The problem that i'm having is not with the scroll working. The problem is that i don't know how much space my text is taking as it can change, so i try to get it by using the CalcHeight function.
And i don't assign a Vector2 variable to the BeginScrollView directly cause i want to make the whole text scrollable...i mean, i don't want to make the text scrollable only through the scrollbars.

Comment: Then the question was not clear at all, i'm afraid. The fact that you double-posted incomplete code (missing variables) makes it even more difficult to understand what you want. I'm assuming you want a ScrollView that expands the interior area of a ScrollView as more text is added?

Comment: As you can see i didn't double-posted, the post was edited by a moderator.
The variable text is retrieved from a database and doesn't change after the user enters this scene. The problem is that i don't know the maximum value that the scroll position can take. So right know the user can scroll way more than it should or, in other words, if the user scrolls down a lot and tries to scroll up again it takes sometime to see the text really scrolling up.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is 3 years later but maybe it will help others too...

I found that setting the `scrollPosition` to a very high number will force the scrollbar to the bottom:

```
scrollPosition.y = 999.9f;
```

Then you can read the position like this:

```
scrollPosition = GUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPosition, 
                                           GUILayout.Width(370),  
                                           GUILayout.Height(135));
```

And it will be set to whatever the maximum is.

Hope this helps!